# Rails: How to escape_javascript with client-side AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

How do I escape a collection when I send it via `to_json` from the controller action *directly* client-side?

- When I say the request is sent from the controller action and then directly to client-side (skips pre-processing) it looks like this:

  - AJAX request gets routed to a controller action
  - Controller Action directly sends the result via javascript to the requester, and on the client-side the requester's javascript would do the processing. something like: `app/assets/javascripts/blogs.js`
- This is as opposed to the request being sent to a controller_action, then to a server-side view for pre-processing, then the results being sent to the requester.  Looks like this:

  - AJAX request
  - Routed to a controller action
  - Sent to a view for pre-process.   Something like: `app/views/blogs/index.js.erb`
  - Results get sent to the requester

***Short Example:***

```
def some_action
  @blogs = Blog.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: @blogs} # currently dangerous, @blogs is not sanitized.
  end
end
```

As an example: assume one of the `@blogs` records in that collection has this data input from a hacker:

```
@blogs.first.title
  => <script>alert('Site now hacked if this javascript runs!')</script>
```

When the `@blogs` get rendered in the browser: I want to escape the `@blogs` content so that the javascript will not get triggered from that hacked entry.

***Longer Example:***

- The user makes a selection for a `blogger` in a select box.
- An AJAX request gets sent which grabs all the `blogs` associated to that selected `blogger`.
- The AJAX request then updates a *second* select box for `blogs` which will now list as options all the `blogs` that belong_to that selected `blogger`.

For the code: the controller action code above would be exactly the same.  Below is the client-side javascript:

**app/assets/javascripts/blogs.js**

```
$("body").on('change', '[data-action="blogger_sel"]', function() {
  var blogs_selection = $(this).closest('[data-parent-for="blogs_sel"]').find('[data-action="blogs_sel"]');
  $.ajax({
    url: "/blogs",
    type: "GET",
    data: {blogger_id: $(this).val()},
    success: function (data) {
      blogs_selection.children().remove();
      $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        blogs_selection.append('<option value=' + item.id + '>' + item.title + '</option>');
       });
     }
   })
 });
```

So up above: the part that I am concerned about is `value.id` and `value.title`.  Those are things that could be dangerous if I do not escape them. I want to make sure it is escaped so that any dangerous input will be rendered harmless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a solution.  Keep in mind that it is often times a good idea to sanitize data before it gets persisted into the database as well.  Also: it is preferable to sanitize server-side before sending the response to the requester:

**app/assets/javascripts/blogs.js**

```
$("body").on('change', '[data-action="blogger_sel"]', function() {
  var blog_sel = $(this).closest('[data-parent-for="blog_sel"]').find('[data-action="blog_sel"]');
  $.ajax({
    url: "/blogs",
    type: "GET",
    data: {blogger_id: $(this).val()},
    success: function (data) {
      blog_sel.children().remove();
      $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        blog_sel.append($('<option>', {
          value: item.id,
          text : item.title
        }));
      });
    }
  })
});
```

**Do not** append options the following way because it will execute dangerous hacks:

```
blogs_selection.append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.title + '</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with an unsanitized HTML string like any other. You need to make it safe before inserting it on your page. All you really need to do is replace the `<` and `>` characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Using this controller as an example:

```
class SomethingController < ApplicationController
  def jsontest
    render json: { blogs: ["<script>alert(1);</script>"] }
  end
end
```

jQuery can do this for you, if you don't mind the clunkiness:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/something/jsontest', 
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) { 
    console.log($('<div>').text(data['blogs'][0]).html()); 
  }
})

> &lt;script&gt;alert(1);&lt;/script&gt;
```

You could also look at using `ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper#sanitize` on the controller side, which will clobber any HTML tags it finds. (Normally this is only available to views, so you could either make a view to render your JSON or `include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper` in your controller). Or do both!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am trying to make it work for my example above but am having trouble.  In attempt to apply your solution: that part that says: `value.title`, I attempted to put your client-side sanitation of: `value.title.html()` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You'd need to do something like this: 

`$('<div>').text(value.title).html()`

The important part is the creation of that in-memory `div` object by jQuery.